# Meteor view doesn't get updated on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, handlebars.js

In my application which is using MeteorJS I have a situation when I have to subscribe to "multiple aspects" of a single collection.

I have a collection called `Invitations`, and on the main page, I subscribe to a publication which publishes those `Invitations`, where the `InvitedUser` is the current user.

Then on a modal dialog, I want to manage those `Invitations` which are *sent* by the current user. I don't want to subscribe to the changes of the sent `Invitations` only on this dialog.

So I decided to manually subscribe to a publication when the dialog is shown to the user and stop this subscription when the modal gets closed.

The code behind for the modal dialog looks something like this:

```
var subscriptionHandle;

Template.invitationsModal.helpers({
    invitations: function() {       
        var activeGroupId = Session.get('activeGroupId');
        var filter = activeGroupId ? {invitedBy: Meteor.user()._id, group: activeGroupId} : {};
        return Invitations.find(filter);
    }
});


Template.invitationsModal.rendered = function() {
    $('#invitationsModal').off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var activeGroupId = Session.get('activeGroupId');
        subscriptionHandle = Meteor.subscribe('sentInvitations', activeGroupId);    
    });
    $('#invitationsModal').off('hidden.bs.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        subscriptionHandle.stop();
    });
};
```

(I left out the unimportant parts.)

In the template I just iterate through the `invitations` helper:

```
<template name="invitationsModal">
    <div id="invitationsModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">                      
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Invitations</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body container-fluid">
                        {{#each invitations}}
                            {{> invitationRow}}
                        {{/each}}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name or email">
                            </div>                              
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default button-add" value="Invite" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This template then included in my main page:

```
{{> invitationsModal}}
```

When I first load the page, the Session variable `activeGroupId` is empty, so wrong data is loaded into the hidden modal. 
When I show the modal to the user, I set the `activeGroupId` to some value, so:

1. the `invitations` helper is executed again because of this change, and now we return the valid list of invitations for the active group.
2. the DOM is updated inside the modal to reflect the change in the 1.)

Now here comes the interesting part: the whole solution works fine on Chrome and Firefox but  not always on IE.

On IE there is one case when the 1.) step runs correctly, but the 2.) is simply not executed.

This is the case when I open the modal for the first time. This time the DOM contains the wrong, unfiltered collection.

When I close and open the modal for the second time (without refreshing the page in the browser), it works fine again.

I don't have any idea what could cause this behavior. Could it be a bug in Meteor, or so?

(Tested in IE11)

Answer (score 0):

A call to `Deps.flush()` magically solved the issue - this is the event handler which shows the dialog to the user:

```
'click .menu-command-invitations': function(e) {
    Session.set('activeGroupId', this._id);
    Deps.flush(); // without this, it won't work in IE
    $('#invitationsModal').modal('show');
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

From [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_flush):

> Deps.flush forces all of the pending reactive updates to complete. 
>   For example, if an event handler changes a Session variable that will
>   cause part of the user interface to rerender, the handler can call
>   flush to perform the rerender immediately and then access the
>   resulting DOM.

Although I don't really know why I need to call this and why it didn't work only under IE.

I'm reading and writing session variables inside other event handlers in the same application and those work perfectly in IE.